# adding new AngularJS controller to main page with userscript

Tags: angularjs, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm trying to develop a script for an online game. They're using angularJS on their pages.

Is it possible to attach my own angular controller, written in userscript, running in tampermonkey? Here is part of my code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Inventory extras
// @version     0.1
// @include     gameurl.com/*/economy/inventory
// @description Table with licenses and taxes in the inventory. Scan for prices in sortable table.  Also checks for the old license bug, when aliens are on top of the list of sellers. Now with job offers.
// @namespace   myNamespace
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = jQuery;

function AddStyle(t) {
    $("head").append("<style>" + t + "</style>");
}

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $("#sell_offers").after('<div class="taxTable" style="display: block;" ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="licensesController">' + '<table id="licenses" width="100%">' + "<thead>" + "<tr>" + '<th style="height: 40px; text-align: center; padding-left: 0px;"> </th>" + "</tr>" + "</thead>" + "<tbody></tbody>" + "</table>" + "</div>");
    $("#inventory_overview .taxTable table tbody").append("<tr ng-repeat='country in countries'><td style='padding-left: 5px;' colspan='9'>{{ 'Country: ' + country.name + ', Locale: ' + country.locale }}</td></tr>");

    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
    mainApp.controller('licensesController', function($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [{locale:'en-US',name:'United States'}, {locale:'en-GB',name:'United Kingdom'}, {locale:'en-FR',name:'France'}]
    });

})();
```

The code is cut for the example and may contain some errors. What should I call to execute my functions at host page?

Yes, I started to read tutorials, but i couldn't find anything about tampermonkey and angularJS.

**Edit1:**

```
$("#sell_offers").after('<div ng-controller="MyController"> Hello {{greetMe}}! </div>'); 
angular.module('myApp', []) 
    .controller('MyController', [
        '$scope', function ($scope) {
             $scope.greetMe = 'World';
        }
    ]);
    angular.element(function() { 
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
})();
```

Still not working. angular.min.1488804924.js:6 Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/ng/btstrpd?p0=%26lt%3Bdiv%20id%3D%22myApp%22%26gt%3B

**Edit2:**

Neither

```
var $ = jQuery;
var ErpkApp = unsafeWindow.ErpkApp;

function AddStyle(t) {
    $("head").append("<style>" + t + "</style>");
}

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $("#sell_offers").after('<div id="myTest" ng-controller="MyController"> Hello {{greetMe}}! </div>');
    ErpkApp.controller('MyController', [
        '$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.greetMe = 'World';
        }
    ]);
})();
```

*I used mainpage's ErpkApp because `<html ng-app="ErpkApp" lang="en">`*

nor

```
var $ = jQuery;

function AddStyle(t) {
    $("head").append("<style>" + t + "</style>");
}

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $("#sell_offers").after('<div id="myTest" ng-controller="MyController"> Hello {{greetMe}}! </div>');
    var app = angular.module('ErpkApp', []);

    app.controller('MyController', [
        '$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.greetMe = 'World';
        }
    ]);
})();
```

works.

**Edit3:**

```
var $ = jQuery;

function AddStyle(t) {
    $("head").append("<style>" + t + "</style>");
}

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $("#sell_offers").after('<div id="myTest"><div ng-controller="MyController"> Hello {{greetMe}}! </div></div>');
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('MyController', [
        '$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.greetMe = 'World';
        }
    ]);

    angular.bootstrap($('#myTest'), ['myApp']);
})();
```

- `userscript.html?id=bbb54573-b5ea-43c3-84eb-119847f9176d:4 ERROR: Execution of script 'game Inventory extras' failed! [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/ng/btstrpd?p0=%26lt%3Bdiv%20id%3D%22myTest%22%26gt%3B`

I think I have to give up. I read that angular don't allow nesting apps. In the main page `html` is already bootstrapped, so I can't attach any new app below.

Comment: you'll need to manually bootstrap your angular app.  see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization.  Essentially, call `angular.bootstrap()` **instead of using `ng-app`**

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, I removed it.

`(function() { 'use strict'; $("#sell_offers").after('<div ng-controller="MyController"> Hello {{greetMe}}! </div>'); angular.module('myApp', []) .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) { $scope.greetMe = 'World'; }]); angular.element(function() { angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']); }); // Your code here... })();`

Still not working. 

angular.min.1488804924.js:6 Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/ng/btstrpd?p0=%26lt%3Bdiv%20id%3D%22myApp%22%26gt%3B

Comment: you should [edit] the question and add code to the question body.  Not only is code not formatted well in comments, but also comments are not permanent, and critical information could be lost.

Comment: that being said, if you are getting an error `"App Already Bootstrapped with this Element"`, that's a pretty good indication that there is already an `ng-app` on the `document` HTML element.  either figure out what that module is named and connect your controller to that module (and skip bootstrapping), or use the element that your app is creating as the bootstrap point instead of `document` (and thus create a second, separate angular app).

Comment: Read, tried many different ways, but still can't manage it to work.

Comment: well, it seems you still have quite a bit to learn about how angularjs works.  I'm trying to guide you through comments, because it's really hard to give you an answer when I can only see half of the code you are working with.

Comment: now that we know what the name of the app module is, you are attaching to it incorrectly.  Specifically, there is a difference between getting an existing module and creating a new module.  in your second example, try `angular.module('ErpkApp');` rather than `angular.module('ErpkApp', []);`.  The first is the *getter* syntax, the second is the *setter* syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! I didn't find any suitable for me tutorial. Either they are for experts or they are in telegraph style.

Actually this is the whole code. I think i can finish all other work when I attach to the original app. 

http://postimg.cc/5Y118dNq

Still not working. No error, no result. http://postimg.cc/JtfxxrWL

Comment: I think you're going to have to take the other route and bootstrap your own app;  The situation you are describing now usually only happens when the controller doesn't exist at the time the HTML is rendered, and that can happen if the controller isn't able to register with the existing app.

Comment: I think I have to give up. I read that angular don't allow nesting apps. In the main page body is already initialized, so I can't attach any new app below. 

Thanks again!